# Radio button no longer showing in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, radio-button

I don't really know how it happened but recently my radio button in Android studio has suddenly vanished my old project shows it as symbol not recognised my XML shows it as Element RadioButton is not allowed here I have created two more new projects but I can't add RadioButton to any of my project again the suggestion is not even coming up but surprisingly when I write it and run my project they work perfectly well but they are despite show red in the project I also try to update my Android studio to the latest version but it still the same error all other symbol are working fine including radiogroup but RadioButton same to have suddenly vanished
Here is a link of the error in picture
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnJMgLR6XMlf31Ci2Jhfi0_ua-Ch5BON/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Attach pictures from what has happened

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnJMgLR6XMlf31Ci2Jhfi0_ua-Ch5BON/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Try file->invalidate caches/restart

Comment: Not still working after invalidate caches/restart

Comment: Restart AS or clean and rebuild the project

Comment: Still No Working